# Random Walk expectation and independence

Tags: probability

This is a question from one of old books, which honestly, I don't have any idea for solve that:

First, suppose that we are at $P_0 = \left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right)$. in step $n$, we are at $P_n = \left(\begin{matrix}x_n \\ y_n \\ z_n\end{matrix}\right)$.

And in step $n+1$ we will in one of these positions:

$P_{n+1} = \Bigg\{P_n \pm \left(\begin{matrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right) , P_n \pm \left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{matrix}\right) , P_n \pm \left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{matrix}\right)\Bigg\}$

all of these 6 positions have the same probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

1. For $n>0$, does $x_n$ and $y_n$ independent?
2. Find $\mathbb{E}\left[|P_n|^2\right]$ in terms of $n$

Well, I don't know how to find out that is $x_n$ and $y_n$ independent or not? I know the definition of dependence, but How can I use that here?
About second question I don't have any Idea btw

Comment: Hint for 1: If $x_n=n$, then you necessarily have $y_n=0$. More generally, information about $x_n$ gives some information about $y_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for 1: If $x_n=n$, then you necessarily have $y_n=0$. More generally, information about $x_n$ gives some information about $y_n$.

Hint for 2: note that $E[|P_n|^2] = E[x_n^2] + E[y_n^2] + E[z_n^2]$ so it suffices to compute each term. In turn, $x_n$ is the sum of i.i.d. random variables that take values $1, 0, -1$ with probabilities $1/6, 2/3, 1/6$ respectively, so you can expand $x_n^2$ as the square of a sum of these random variables and proceed.

Comment: I find $\mathbb{E}\left[|P_n|\right]=n$. am I right?